# C++ primer 5th edition: Unnamed enumeration creating objects

Tags: c++, enums

Hello I have this text from C++ primer 5th edition: "Enumerations":

> `enum {floatPrec = 6, doublePrec = 10, double_doublePrec = 10};`
>
> If the `enum` is unnamed, we may define objects of that type only as part of the `enum` definition. As with a class definition, we can provide a comma separated list of declarators between the close curly and the semicolon that ends the `enum` definition (§ 2.6.1, p. 73).

- But I can use `auto` type specifier or `decltype` to get the type of an unnamed `enum` from an expression:

  ```
  enum {RED = 1, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA};
  auto bk_color = GREEN;

  std::cout << typeid(bk_color).name() << '\n';
  decltype(ALPHA) fg_color = RED;
  std::cout << typeid(fg_color).name() << '\n';
  ```

The output:

```
Z4mainEUt_
Z4mainEUt_
```

- So I think it is a mistake in the book, isn't it? Thank you!

Comment: To save people some research, the 5th edition was in 2012 with C++11 explicitly taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

The chapter means object definitions may be like this:

```
enum {RED = 1, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA} bk_color = GREEN, fg_color = RED;
```

The chapter does not mean such is the only possible definition.

---

Sorry, I missed "we may define objects of that type **only** as part of the enum". Then this is an obsolete information in the chapter. I suppose it was forgotten to be edited.